# Convert EditText in a "spinner"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

In the work they asked me to do a activity like that:

[image]

And the "category" when clicked has to show a list of categories. but, they want as the same look and feel as a edittext.

How can I do it, without to be a spinner? Is there any option? or that functionallity must be a spinner?

Comment: I assume the easiest way would be to extend a textBox and implement a custom `onClick(View v)` method that pops up a dialog with a set of possible entries, however, pop-up dialog has quite a bit of different characteristics than a drop-down menu that spinner offers.

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you convince your employer otherwise. Spinners look different from EditTexts for a reason. When changing the look and feel of a Spinner to the one of an EditText, it will confuse users and create uncertainty about the functionality of the input field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest replacing your layout's EditText with a AutoCompleteTextView.

[image: Example of AutoCompleteTextView]

You can then provide a list adapter much in the same way as you would provide an adapter into a Spinner:

```
mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(suggestions);
```

Comment: I'm gonna try your option, in this days and I'll comment how it works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use spinner only. But change the background of spinner with the custom background Like
editText background with that right arrow.Take that background from ur graphic designers.

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/categories"
android:background="@drawable/custombackground"/>
```